# JavaScript set Image/Element source/attribute is not updating the Image/Element

Tags: javascript, html, image, attributes, element

I'm trying to change the `src` attribute of an image each time a button is clicked, and when the last image appears, then it resets and displays the initial image.

I get the `src` attribute of the image, and update it to new image, but the image does not change.

```
  var imgSrc = document.querySelector("#myImg").src;
  imgSrc = images[i]; /* Is not working */
```

Could you help me please? Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <img width="60%" id="myImg" src="https://i.imgur.com/TiipKoJ.gif"/>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="changeImg ()">Change Image</button>

  <script>
    var i = 0, images = ["https://i.imgur.com/TiipKoJ.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/QHOn5G9.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/wRbhXbc.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/wbegtAO.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/UIXLgFX.gif"];

    function changeImg() {
      var imgSrc = document.querySelector("#myImg").src;

      if (i < 3) {
        i++;
        imgSrc = images[i];
      } else {
        i = 0;
        imgSrc = images[i];
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to update `src` property also i.e. `document.querySelector("#myImg").src = imgSrc `

Comment: This statement : `var imgSrc = document.querySelector("#myImg").src;` wil *copy* the value, since it's a string. You have a set the value directly : `document.querySelector("#myImg").src = "./whatever.png"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What your code does

```
  var imgSrc = document.querySelector("#myImg").src;
  /* store src attribute of the image in a variable named imgSrc */

  imgSrc = images[i];
  /* store new image in variable imgSrc */
```

> What you need to do

```
  var img = document.querySelector("#myImg");
  /* store object reference of the image in a variable named img */

  img.src = images[i];
  /* update src attribute of the image by object reference stored in variable img */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <img width="60%" id="myImg" src="https://i.imgur.com/TiipKoJ.gif">
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="changeImg ()">Change Image</button>


  <script>
    var i = 0, images = ["https://i.imgur.com/TiipKoJ.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/QHOn5G9.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/wRbhXbc.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/wbegtAO.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/UIXLgFX.gif"];

    function changeImg() {
      var img = document.querySelector("#myImg");

      if (i < 3) {
        i++;
        img.src = images[i];
      } else {
        i = 0;
        img.src = images[i];
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were updating the value in a variable, which does not get reflected in your HTML.

Update

```
imgSrc = images[i];
```

to

```
document.getElementById("myImg").setAttribute("src", images[i]);
```

**Working Version**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <img width="60%" id="myImg" src="https://i.imgur.com/TiipKoJ.gif"></img>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="changeImg ()">Change Image</button>


  <script>
    var i = 0;

    function changeImg() {
      var img = document.getElementById("myImg"); // get the element
      var images = ["https://i.imgur.com/TiipKoJ.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/QHOn5G9.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/wRbhXbc.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/wbegtAO.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/UIXLgFX.gif"];

      if (i < 3) {
        i++;
      } else {
        i = 0;
      }
     // you can move the setAttribute statement after if/else block.
      img.setAttribute("src", images[i]); 

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a way simpler way.
Juste keep track of which image from `images` is currently displayed with `i`.

Whenever the image changes, increment `i`. If `i` reached the end of `images`, reset it to `0`.

```js
var i = 0;
var images = ["https://i.imgur.com/TiipKoJ.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/QHOn5G9.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/wRbhXbc.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/wbegtAO.gif", "https://i.imgur.com/UIXLgFX.gif"];

function changeImg() {
  if(i<images.length) i++;
  else i=0;
  document.querySelector("#myImg").src = images[i];
}
```

```html
<img width="60%" id="myImg" src="https://i.imgur.com/TiipKoJ.gif"></img>
<br><br>
<button onclick="changeImg ()">Change Image</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<img width="60%" id="myImg" src="https://i.imgur.com/TiipKoJ.gif"></img>
<br><br>
<button onclick = "changeImg()">Change Image</button>

<script>


var i = 0;

function changeImg () {
 var images = ["https://i.imgur.com/TiipKoJ.gif","https://i.imgur.com/QHOn5G9.gif","https://i.imgur.com/wRbhXbc.gif","https://i.imgur.com/wbegtAO.gif","https://i.imgur.com/UIXLgFX.gif"];
 i++;
 if (i>3) {
  i=0;
 }
 document.querySelector("#myImg").src = images[i];
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

you can't save a var like you did: var imgSrc = document.querySelector("#myImg").src;

just use it directly. hope I could help!

greetings